# Too much disk space being use in the server when doing a build

Tags: build, bamboo, diskspace, docker-build

How do I prevent individual task to build independently in/by the docker remote agent(s) during build?

Comment: If you want to reduce the space used in your Docker builds, run a clean-up step at the end of each RUN section. E.g., clean the apt cache in the same RUN block as you update and install stuff with apt. Then you'll avoid having that cache stored in one of your layers.

Comment: But, you should provide more details. Are you just trying to minimize the size of the final image, or do you have restrictions on the temporary space you can use too?